# How to change part of window content upon combo box selection changed event?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

In my wpf window I want to change part of it (make different controls visible) when combo box selection is changed. Exactly like TabControl works, just with combobox. I know I could just make some controls visible while hiding the others in the c# code behind but I want to find out if there are other -better solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use two `Grid` or `GroupBox` (or other container type) controls and put appropriate set of controls in each of them. This way you can just visibility of panels to hide the whole set of controls instead of hiding each control directly.

It may sometimes be appropriate to create a user control for each set of controls. However, this can depend on a specific case.

Comment: I have tried GroupBox it works. However, I can't find anything named Panel in my toolbox. Is it called differently?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't noticed it's WPF. You can encapsulate it in any container, like `Grid` or `StackPanel`. I'll update my answer to correct.